# Limit of $\frac{x}{a+x}$

Tags: limits

Why is it that when I look at $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{a+x}$$

I don't know the answer because it's an  indeterminate form, but if I divide by x

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{a}{x}+1}$$

the answer appears "magically"  ?

What happened ?

Comment: as  $\frac{a}{x} \rightarrow 0$ as  $ x  \rightarrow \infty $ if $a$ is real , then your limit is 1.

Comment: That is because you know any number divided by $\infty$ is zero but you don't know what is $\infty$ divided by $\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mystery in the phrase “indeterminate form”: it just means that you have a limit where you can't directly apply any of the general theorems on limits that can be instead applied in other situations.

For instance,
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{2x+1}{3x+2}=\frac{3}{5}
$$
because you know the theorem that says

> if both $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=m$ exist, are finite and $m\ne0$, then $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{l}{m}$$

(Note that $a$ can be $\infty$ or $-\infty$.)

This theorem can be supplemented with other cases; for instance, if $l=\infty$ and $m>0$ (but still finite), then $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$. Other criteria can be applied when $m=0$ (with some care).

However, no general criterion exists when both limits are $0$ or both are infinity ($\infty$ or $-\infty$).

In these cases one can get away by rewriting the function in a different form and this is exactly the “magic” you did.

Since you're considering the limit at $\infty$, you can assume the function is defined in some interval $(b,\infty)$ so that $b>0$ and $b>-a$. Hence, for $x\in(b,\infty)$, we can write
$$
\frac{x}{a+x}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{x}}
$$
and now we *can* apply the above theorem, because the numerator and the denominator both have limit $1$.

We could apply l'Hôpital, but it would be overkill:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{a+x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1}=1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The result is not ''magic'' but a consequence of the [property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties):

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow p}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\dfrac{\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)}{\lim_{x\rightarrow p}g(x)}
$$

Use this (two fold) to evalate
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\dfrac{\frac {f(x)}{x}}{\frac {g(x)}{x}}
$$

Comment: I understand that it works, I just find strange that the limit should be indeterminate in one expression, and obvious in an equivalent expression.

Comment: The first equality holds provided both limits in the right-hand side exist; I believe this should be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The value of $\frac{x}{a+x}$ at $x=\infty$ is indeterminate.

But

The value of $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{a+x}=1$

Or

The value of $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{a}{x}+1}=1$

Above two equations are equivalent.

It's just that if we put directly $x=\infty$ in the given expression then we won't get any value because no value of $\frac{x}{a+x}$ exists at $x=\infty$ but if we want the closest value of $$\frac{x}{a+x}$$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$ then we'll get $1$.
It's the essence of limit and follows from definition of limit.